# Is there any way to stop the tabs coming up with the keyboard in android?

Tags: android, keyboard, tabs, move

I am making an app that supports all versions of android (just in case it is relevant), but when the user clicks on an app, the keyboard pops up and moves the tabs with it. Is there anyway to stop the tabs from doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try giving android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" inside the manifest file for the activity.

Comment: @ NotACleverMan This is not working for me Can u tell me where actually i have to place this code inside the Mainfest.

Answer (score 1):

write this android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" in tabActivity class in manifest file.