# keyboard lifts tabview above

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-tabactivity

In my app, when I click on `EditText` keyboard lifts the `TabView` above. I have used this `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"` in Android manifest file. I am using activity group. So I used this in both activity and activity group. In activity programmatically I used this

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

But no success.

In `TabActivty` class I have four tabs. I am using `ActivityGroup`. I don't know where I am doing somthing wrong.

In **Manifest file** I used this in activty group and activity

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of this question


   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956993/is-there-any-way-to-stop-the-tabs-coming-up-with-the-keyboard-in-android/4957178#4957178

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by specifying android:windowSoftInputMode"adjustResize | adjustPan" in tabactivity.

Answer (score 0):

add this permin your manifest might help
         " android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden""

```
      <activity android:name=".MyActivity"
      android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that setting the following value in your activity tag in your manifest should do the trick :

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Comment: Thanks for rply. But i have tried this. But problem still exist.